# Doing incremental backups of a minecraft server with large 6GB-15GB sqlite database files amongst the server files

Tags: rsync, backup, tar, minecraft

I am running a minecraft server on a VPS somewhere in Canada.
I am using rsync to sync the server files from the VPS to my PC. That works fine and nice. However I want to make tar.gz archives of the server files on my PC.

What I wish to do is make a full tar.gz backup of the minecraft server files I currently have on my PC. Lets name that backup full.tar.gz. Then a month later I use rsync to sync the minecraft server files from the VPS to my PC.
Then I wish to do a backup of the minecraft server files in a tar.gz archive but only with the changed files since the last full backup. Lets name that backup incremental-01.tar.gz. Another month later I wish do the same and make backup named incremental-02.tar.gz which only has changes since the full.tar.gz and incremental-01.tar.gz backups and so on and so on. I can do all of that without issues using tar.

But here is the catch. There are some quite large files amongst the server files 6GB-15GB. These large files are sqlite database files. Only just a portion of these huge files change. I dont wish to include the whole 6GB-15GB sqlite database files every time I make an incremental tar backup.

I am looking for a solution that can do the beforementioned icremental backup operations and for large files it would only backups changes that happend inside the large files since the last backups.

It would be even better to have a backup solution that would make incremental backups on binary level and not just backup whole files if their meta data or crc32 or hash or whatever is different since the last backup

Comment: `tar` is file-based, so even a single-byte change to a file will mean that the entire file is captured in an incremental backup. `rsync` is (usually) block-based, so that same single-byte change to a file will result in only that block (plus checksums for the remaining blocks) being transferred. Maybe a suitable approach could be to discard the initial generation of `tar` files and instead use `rsync` directly?

Comment: with incremental backups as archives and `rsync`, making a new incremental backup you always need an unpacked `fullbackup.tar.gz` first and compare from there. With `rsync` you can make use of options like `-c --compare-dest=` or `-b --backup-dir` and use `--exclude=sqlite` to achieve this. I would recommend to take a look at `BorgBackup` which is a fork from `attic`, there you have deduplication which could be handy for `sqlite`, as it stores only new chunks of a file. Also check how you create a reliable backup of your sqlite DB in conjunction with minecraft as application.